# Multiple image select from gallery

Tags: android

I am a beginner at Android.

I want to select multiple images from gallery and view them to a horizontal scroll view. Currently I'm able to select a single image and view it. I have referred a single imageView's id for viewing purposes. But a google search on 'selecting of multiple images' made me realize that I need to use GridView, recycler view or listview. I'm still not clear on the solution. Any help?

Comment: horizontal scroll view is only a parent view it needs some child view place GridView, recycler view or listview and use adapter classses to get multiple images

Comment: What to do mean by upload? Are you uploading on server or want to show images in horizontal scroll view?

Comment: You can use 3rd party library like  [Awesome Image Picker](https://github.com/myinnos/AwesomeImagePicker)

Comment: @nithiny.n.v   thankyou for the info. can you tell me which adapter classes I can use for my requirement?

Comment: @Avi just view on horizontal scroll view after selection from gallery

Comment: Its better to use image picker: Few multiple image picker you can use : - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5632 - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5241 - https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker **Update 1: added more links** - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1713 - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4395 - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4320

Comment: @YashashreeBarhate u need to implement custom adapter classes there are lot of tutorials  available on google

Comment: You can use https://github.com/avirepo/imagepicker it will return the image what you want just provide the number when launching it.

Comment: @Avi Thanks a lot! imagepicker is exactly how i wanted ! :D

Comment: Most welcome, please like the library so other can also have its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Start activity to choose your image with this intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), UploadingHelper.REQUEST_CODE);
```

then select any number of images you want and then in your activity result

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && intent.getClipData() != null) {
            int numberOfImages = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
try {
      ImageData imageData = new ImageData();
      imageData.uri = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

      Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());
     imageData.icon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, getPixelsFromDP(widthOfImages), getPixelsFromDP(widthOfImages), false);

      images.add(imageData);
      } catch (Exception e) {
              Logger.log(e);
           }
      }

}
```

This is the Image Data class used.

```
public class ImageData {
        public Bitmap icon;
        public Uri uri;
}
```

Sorry I forgot add the method

```
private int getPixelsFromDP(float dp) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,  Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou. And then after selecting, how do we display it on the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: can you give me an example with xml file too?

Comment: I can but it is hard to post it here cause it is really a long post. Create a list of ImageData and add all those received images on that. Use that list to list to add your Images into your views. And Instead of using Horizontal Scroll view use RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManger.Horizontal

Comment: Okay! i'll try! Thankyou :)